# Xamarin Android Binding Project

Tags: android, xamarin, binding

I'm trying to build a Xamarin binding project to the Android SDK for the ACR1225U bluetooth card reader.

I'm struggling to get past the first build after adding the AAR file.  One of the generated files is implementing a method which doesn't match the method defined on the interface its implementing.  I'm getting the following exception.

```
'GetPropertyAction' does not implement interface member 'IPrivilegedAction.Run()'. 'GetPropertyAction.Run()' cannot implement 'IPrivilegedAction.Run()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Object'.
```

The code automatically generated is:

```
[Register ("run", "()Ljava/lang/String;", "GetRunHandler")]
public virtual unsafe string Run ()
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the managedReturn type of `GetPropertyAction.Run()` to be `Object`, but not sure if that is `System.Object` or `Java.Lang.Object`. My guess would be `Java.Lang.Object`.

Docs on how to change the return type:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata#managedreturn

> managedReturn
>   Changes the return type of a method. This does not change the return attribute (as changes to return attributes can result in incompatible changes to the JNI signature). In the following example, the return type of the append method is changed from SpannableStringBuilder to IAppendable (recall that C# does not support covariant return types):

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='<replace.with.the.actual.name.of.the.package.in.java>']/
      class[@name='GetPropertyAction']/
      method[@name='Run']" 
      name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
```

Something like that should work.